# How to control depth of tree weaklearner with Matlab's fitensemble

Tags: matlab, classification, adaboost

I'm using Matlab's fitensemble function on a data with 8 features and 5000 samples.
With the following command I can train a model:

```
ada= fitensemble(datafeatures,dataclass,'AdaBoostM1',200,'tree');
```

My question: How can I create weak learners with one single split (two leafs instead of many leafs)?
I know the following command controls the way the trees are created: 
`t = ClassificationTree.template`, but I only see minimal parameters for tree depth. How can I set an *upper* limit?

Answer (score 0):

use it:

```
t = templateTree('minleaf',5);
ens = fitensemble(X,Y,'AdaBoostM2',50,t);
```

you can see:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ensemble-methods.html

Answer (score 0):

With following three parameters you are able to control depth or leafiness of a tree.

1-  MaxNum: Set a large value for MaxNumSplits to get a deep tree

2-  MinLeaf: Set small values of MinLeafSize to get deep trees

3-  MinParent: Set small values of MinParentSize to get deep trees

And this is a way that you can set them up. Assumed, you use AdaBoost for a multi classification problem.

DTree = templateTree('MinLeaf',1,'MinParent',4);

Ensemble=fitensemble(Train,Respones,'AdaBoostM2',500,DTree);

Check this link for more detail:

http://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/classification-trees-and-regression-trees.html#bsw6baj